# Heroku sending ping with SingalR-websocket error

Tags: asp.net-core, heroku, signalr

Hello I uploaded a server asp.net core 3.1 https://networkscanner.herokuapp.com/
ping checker to Heroku and when i push the button to check i get Heroku error

**It is important to note when the server is on my localhost he is fine**

```
2020-04-11T12:06:01.928201+00:00 app[web.1]: ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The system's ping utility could not be found.
2020-04-11T12:06:01.928202+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetPingProcess(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
2020-04-11T12:06:01.928202+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendWithPingUtility(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeout, PingOptions options)
```

And this is my code

```
    async void SendPing()
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        int timeout = 10000;
        string d = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(d);
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
        PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(this.numbers.Address, timeout, buffer, options);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            endPoint.ip = reply.Address.ToString();
            endPoint.isUP = true;
            endPoint.ms = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
            result.status = 200;
            result.message = "OK";
            result.endPoint = endPoint;
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", result);
        }
        else
        {
            endPoint.ip = reply.Address.ToString();
            result.message = reply.Status.ToString();
            endPoint.isUP = false;
            result.status = 400;
            result.endPoint = endPoint;
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", result);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Your error is "Platform not supported".  What library is the "Ping" class coming from?  What platform does that library support? And what platform are you running on?    The class looks like it may be trying to reach a system level ping process that just doesn't exist on your OS.

Comment: @Mike Wodarczyk You know a library that sends a ping Or from heroku internal server?

Comment: I don’t know which library is the source for the Ping class, but you can find out. Put the cursor on the word Ping on the command new Ping() and hit F12 if you are using visual studio. It will take you to the source. It will probably not be source code, but some call level deco piled representation of the source. At the top is usually the  namespace which is usually also the library name. Searching for that library name and Ping should give you more information about what systems it supports.